# Extraction of keywords from string data pandas

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I have a dataframe where I have column named 'difference' which has instances like these:

```
Backward compatibility errors (2):
error at original_source=specs/994.json, in API POST /echo api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. 

error at original_source=specs/994.json, in API GET /users/{username} api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation].
```

I want to extract three things from this column, the keyword named `Backward compatibility errors` under `errors`, the number in brackets in `count` and lastly the content inside square brackets under `content` column.

This is the code which I am using right now:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df['difference']=df['difference'].astype(str)
keywords_regex = {
    'errors': r'(\w+ errors)',
    'count': r'\((\d+)\)',
    'content': r'\[(.*?)\]'
}

def extract_keywords(text):
    keywords = {}
    for name, regex in keywords_regex.items():
        keywords[name] = re.findall(regex, text)
    return pd.Series(keywords)
df[list(keywords_regex.keys())] = df['difference'].apply(extract_keywords)
```

This code does extract the required information, however it is all under `[]` brackets, I tried a few solutions to remove it here on stack, but they don't seem to work. Does anyone know of a better way I could achieve this? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's because `re.findall` returns a list. Do you want to unpack the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know *a priori* that the "errors" and "count" lists will only have one item, you can use that like this (I've included a boolean for each regex to indicate that we should take the first item in the list):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

keywords_regex = {
    'errors': [r'(\w+ errors)',True],
    'count': [r'\((\d+)\)',True],
    'content': [r'\[(.*?)\]',False]
}

def extract_keywords(text):
    keywords = {}
    for name, r in keywords_regex.items():
        keywords[name] = re.findall(r[0], text)
        if r[1]:
            keywords[name] = keywords[name][0]
    return pd.Series(keywords)

t = """Backward compatibility errors (2):
error at original_source=specs/994.json, in API POST /echo api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. 

error at original_source=specs/994.json, in API GET /users/{username} api path removed without deprecation [api-path-removed-without-deprecation]. """

s = extract_keywords(t)
s
```

... which produces `s` as follows:

```
errors                                  compatibility errors
count                                                      2
content    [api-path-removed-without-deprecation, api-pat...
dtype: object
```

This revised function could be used with the dataframe in the same way as the original function:

```
df[list(keywords_regex.keys())] = df['difference'].apply(extract_keywords)
```

Comment: I used the string so that I could create a self-contained example. I'll adjust it to suit your need.

Comment: This gives me a `list index out of range` error

Comment: That'll happen if one of the entries in your dataframe column does not have a match returned by the `findall()` call. As I noted, this solution works if you know *a priori* that the "errors" and "count" lists will only have one item (and neither more nor less than one). The ability to handle zero, one or more matches is why `findall()` returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Pandas' builtin method:

```
out = df['diff_2'].str.extractall(r'|'.join(keywords_regex.values()))
out.columns=list(keywords_regex.keys())
```

Output:

```
                       errors count                               content
  match                                                                  
0 0      compatibility errors   NaN                                   NaN
  1                       NaN     2                                   NaN
1 0                       NaN   NaN  api-path-removed-without-deprecation
2 0                       NaN   NaN  api-path-removed-without-deprecation
```